# Creating a Ludo game

Tags: java

I've been given an assignment the hand in on Wednesday and it is to create a Ludo game. I have the jist of everything working but I cannot figure out how to make the player pawns take a set path. so obviously the board is in a + looking shape and the pawns move around the board. Is there anyway I can set it so that they all follow that path.

My idea would be to have a int[][] pos of each "tile" and depending on which player you are, it starts at a different position in the list. So e.g:

```
pos[0][5]
pos[5][10]<First tile a red pawn should start
pos[10][15]
pos[15][20]<First tile  a blue pawn should start
pos[20][25]
```

and then loop through this list of positions until the win condition is satisfied.
This is my idea but I was hoping there maybe another way

Comment: What's wrong with your idea? Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: @tobias_k its mainly because I don't have much time and would rather a good idea other than run around for the next few days

Comment: In Ludo each colour has its own final track. Does your variant include that? If it does, then you cannot move pieces of different colours along the same track for the entire game.

Comment: Maybe you could make a Tile class that contains which pawns are currently on that tile and keep 4 arrays of tiles for the path of every color. Then you can easily find which tile comes next for every color.

Comment: Since you have to hand in a week, keep it simple. If you give each of four tokens their own place in the starting and finishing area, which makes drawing them easier, a Ludo board has 104 locations and each of 16 pieces has a unique path of 59 steps. Whilst creating a 16x59 array may look like a chore now it is simple and once you are done you will have all movements clearly defined.

Comment: @DaanvanderKallen this is a good shout, I did not think of that. Thank you!

Comment: @SimonG. That is a good shout, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

As Daan van der Kallen mentioned, for games which include tiles and multiple pieces, you can implement a tile class which can keep track of the pieces on that tile. For Ludo, you may want a subclass for tiles in the home run which only red/blue/... can travel on. Maybe a home tile which is the finish place as well as a "start"/"park"/[I've heard many names given to this tile, so depends on your version of Ludo] tile (where the pieces start and return to).

This will also allow you to display each tile for later, and can also help you implement certain rules e.g. 2 blue on a tile does not allow other colours through. etc.