# Referencing Graphics objects

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am creating a Ludo game and each player has 4 separate play pieces, each one of these pieces are using a

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.drawRect(...);
```

How would I be able to reference each of these separate piece as some of them can only move at certain times. i.e
everyone starts with 1 counter but if a 1 or 6 is rolled, a new piece enters the game.

Comment: making multiple stories of your question is the way to GO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939213/storing-x-and-y-positions-on-a-jpanel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918590/creating-a-ludo-game

Comment: @gpasch different errors arise my friend

Answer (score 1):

Keep an ArrayList of Objects you want to paint. The Object might contain information like:

1. location
2. size
3. color.

Then your keep a reference to each Object and when you change one of the 3 properties, you repaint the panel and all the Objects will be painted with the current state of the Object.

For an example to get you started check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The example shows how to create the custom Object and paint all the Objects in an ArrayList. It will be up to you to manage the properties of each Object.

Answer (score 0):

`drawRect` doesn't create a rectangle object that you can reference later. It draws the rectangle directly to the graphics buffer and then forgets about it.

So if you want to have rectangles that can move, you have to create a class that represents those objects and paints them on demand. Then you can move them and repaint the whole scene by calling the paint methods of all objects.

Comment: is there anyway you believe I should go about this?